# On iOS, can presentViewController cause an overflow (like a stack overflow)?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

Since we can call `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated` (which is `dismissViewController` with animation specified first), it seems like a stack structure, where we can present 3 times, and dismiss 3 times, like a chain of a "presenting" view controller as the head, and a "presented" view controller, which is actually another "presenting" view controller itself.

If this is the case, can it actually overflow after some `N` times -- if we keep on calling `presentViewController` in the new view controller but never do a dismiss.  The documentation doesn't seem to warn that there is a possibility.

Comment: I think it's like a linked list, so there is no fixed limit. You'll probably run out of memory first.

Comment: by the way, why does stack overflow so quickly?  Isn't it theoretically possible to easily have a stack of thousand levels or more, if each thread can have access to 4GB?

Comment: On iOS, no thread will have a 4GB stack... Maybe iPhone 15.

Comment: oh I mean in general, like on an iMac...

Comment: By the way, isn't view controller and view heavy objects?  I have an app that keeps on presenting new view controllers, but after the 10th times, the total allocation bytes shown in Instruments is only 7.56 MB... I do it 6 more times and it is 11MB... so maybe it is not a good idea to keep presenting, because it can run out of memory up to a certain point... and we are talking about 25MB on older iOS device and 50MB on newer devices?

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, no. Write an infinite `presentViewController` test case and see what happens. Most probably you’ll hit the memory limit. If this is not a purely theoretical question and you’re thinking about writing an interface that way, then don’t, find another way to do it.